# MySQL Error No. 150 when creating table

Tags: mysql, database

I've tried reading through some of the other threads on here and I don't seem to be doing anything wrong. Could you please give some insight as to what I'm doing wrong here?

This is my student table (creates just fine):

```
    -- STUDENT TABLE
    CREATE TABLE student
    (
    studentID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    lname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    phone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    );
```

And this is my group table (throws error 150):

```
    -- GROUP TABLE
    CREATE TABLE wa_group (
    groupID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    groupName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    groupDetail VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
    groupSize INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 100,
    adminID INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (adminID)
        REFERENCES student (studentID)
        ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column

```
adminID INT NOT NULL
```

does not allow `null` values by your definition.

But later you define

```
ON DELETE SET NULL 
ON UPDATE SET NULL
```

That does not work. Either allow `null` or don't set it to `null` on deletes and updates.

Comment: Hah, who would've thought! Nice catch! Thanks a bunch. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the table referenced by foreign key exists and it's engine supports foreign keys (i.e. You can't reference MyISAM tables from InnoDB ones.)

Comment: Thanks, but both tables use InnoDB and support foreign keys. The problem was more logical as pointed out by @juergen d

Comment: I'm not surprised, I just wasn't sure if MySQL would catch it at create or would wait until the first time the actions were triggered so I figured I might as well present this possibility.

Comment: Yeah same here, but I'm relatively new to this and haven't started experimenting with engines other than InnoDB. That pretty much has full support for foreign keys and constraints so was pretty sure that wasn't it.

Comment: @ShahraizT. Yeah, InnoDB has no problem, but you can have tables from both engines in the same schema (this kind of thing happens a lot when people are trying to reference older tables that have not been changed over).